# select() hanging indefinitely

Tags: c++, networking, select, rtsp

I have an application that runs on embedded linux (older kernel, 2.6.18).  I'm using Live555.  Occasionally when the camera is heavily loaded, my RTSP server (built using Live555) will hang indefinitely--no amount of connecting or cajoling seems to get it to snap out of it, short of resetting the application.

I narrowed the hang down to this code:

```
static int blockUntilReadable(UsageEnvironment& env,
                  int socket, struct timeval* timeout) {
  int result = -1;
  do {
    fd_set rd_set;
    FD_ZERO(&rd_set);
    if (socket < 0) break;
    FD_SET((unsigned) socket, &rd_set);
    const unsigned numFds = socket+1;

    result = select(numFds, &rd_set, NULL, NULL, timeout);  <--HANG
```

timeout is, of course, a NULL pointer which indicates it should block until one of the sockets is readable.  Problem is: it doesn't matter if I connect to the RTSP server--it simply blocks indefinitely.

I did a netstat -an, and it always outputs something like:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5800            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5802            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp       21      0 0.0.0.0:554             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When it's in a failed state, I always see 21 on the Recv-Q, which is "The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket."

Does anyone have any idea what might be going south, or how I could troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks pretty solid. I'm a little curious as to why you're casting to `unsigned int`, but it shouldn't hurt anything.

Some thoughts:

It's not hanging where you think it is. Hopefully you've double/triple checked this. (Check it again?)

Your netstat interpretation is wrong. That part, as the man page notes, is for "Established" sockets - yours is a listener, which is the next sentence: "Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the current syn backlog."

That looks like a huge backlog... Which leads me to think you're not accept()-ing, perhaps because you're stuck in select(). That *is* the select() on your listening socket right?

Last, double check that **you're calling select() on the right socket**. ie, print out that socket arg, and see if it is what it should be.

Essentially, verify: 1) it's is hanging in select() and 2) the arguments to select are correct. I suspect one of those two are not true.

Comment: “Is *socket* the listening/accepting socket?” was my first thought, too.

Comment: Aye, my suspicion is that `socket` is ending up with an incorrect value here.

Comment: Thanks Thanatos.  FWIW, this isn't my code--it's part of the open source RTSP lib, Live555.

I am positive it's hanging in select().  I am not positive the arguments to select are correct, so I'll validate that.  And thanks for the heads up on the netstat changes.